# Having trouble with getting code to find median correctly Java

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure out how to use the quick select algorithm correctly to find the median of an array at an efficiency of o(n). I have tried to code it as such and it doesn't find the correct median. Im just a little stuck with what I am doing that needs to change in order to find the right median.

Here is my code as of now.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int count = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    int houses = in.nextInt();
    ArrayList <Integer> array = new ArrayList <Integer>();

    while (count < houses)
    {
        array.add(in.nextInt());
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(median(array, houses));
    in.close();
}


public static int median (ArrayList <Integer> array, int k)
{
    int median = 0;
    int lpos = 0;
  int rpos = 0;
    int pivot = k/2;
    int length = k/2;
    ArrayList <Integer> leftArray = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    ArrayList <Integer> rightArray = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    if (array.size() == 1)
    {
        return array.get(0); 
    }
  else if (array.size() < pivot)
  {
     return array.get(pivot);
  }
    else
    {
        for (int i=0; i < array.size()-1; i++)
        {
            if (array.get(i) <= array.get(pivot))
            {
                leftArray.add(array.get(i));
           lpos++;
            }
            else 
            {
                rightArray.add(array.get(i));
           rpos++;
            }
        }

        if (leftArray.size() == length)
        {
            return array.get(pivot);
        }
        else if (leftArray.size() > length)
        {
            return median(leftArray, length-1);
        }
        else
        {
            return median(rightArray, length-leftArray.size()-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay from the code you show here I can see two things. You are taking a series of numbers.  First number is number of "houses" and then taking in that many ints into an array.  Passing this array to your median function and doing a single pass of a sort based on the value that is currently in the length/2(pivot) place.

Comment: after this you are passing only a part of the array back depending on the size of the leftArray.size.  and can only pass the left back if it is greater size than 1/2 the original array.

Comment: I don't see where int median variable comes into play in this particular instance

Comment: Now if you wan to truly find the correct median(the number that is in the middle array and the middle value of the original array you would need to do a full sort and then pick the (length-1)/2 for pivot.

Comment: See I dont fully understand the algorithm of quick select using the kth smallest element and using that to find the median of an array

Comment: ahh ok so you are doing a kth smallest element or what would be the median value k/2 length of the array or what element in the array should be the median and find this without a sort?

Comment: If this is the case then your question statement needs editing.  But I can answer that for you.

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the array?

Comment: I dont think I should be otherwise the efficiency wouldnt be o(n) anymore right?

Comment: If you do a quick sort its time complexity with a good algorithm is n logn much better than a bubble sort.  If you can use the built in java list sort it has the highest efficiency using multiple styles depending on size and types of data.

Comment: Then picking the kth smallest element is as simple as accessing the location for k from the sorted array